# Code after while loop that has socket listening never executes

Tags: python, sockets

I have a p2p network and I want to get ping of all clients within 10 seconds so I have a while loop that executes for 10 seconds then it must break out of loop but apparently it never happens and I don't know why.

```py
from socket import *

server_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
server_socket.bind(('', line)) #line is server address
online = []

for p in clients: #clients is all clients address
    server_socket.sendto('ping'.encode(), p)

end = time.time() + 10
while time.time() < end:
    message, peer = server_socket.recvfrom(1024)
    print('pong ', peer)
    online.append(peer)

print('online: ', online) #this line never executes
```

Comment: Are you getting any of the `pong` messages? Did you try to check whether the `online` list gets new values? Did you try to check what results you get for `time.time()`, and how they compare to `end`?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel yes `print('pong ', peer)` gets **pong** answer of clients. I checked whether while loop finish or not and it finished after 10 seconds

Comment: Okay, and what if you print the `time.time()` results inside the loop? Are they increasing? Do they increase beyond the `end` value?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel oh no it is stuck. they are not increasing

Comment: I think `recvfrom()` is blocking yes?

Comment: it is a blocking call, i.e. it will wait until there is that much data to read. But if it actually is blocking then you would not see the `print` inside the loop until that data is available.

Comment: It’s a blocking call. Count the pongs and exit the loop after you get `len(clients)` responses.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Thank you for response. It can't be done because some clients may not respond so it is not always the same length

Comment: Set a timeout on the socket as well with `server_socket.settimeout()`